# ABCpdf AddImageHtml text stretches without administrator rights

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, abcpdf

**Problem:**
When I run the same program admin vs. non-admin they produce different results.

**Example:**

[image: PDF problem]

As you can see without administrator rights the text gets stretched vertically.

**Code to reproduce:**

```
var html = File.ReadAllText( "htmldata.txt" );
using( var doc = new Doc() )
{
    doc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Chrome;
    doc.Page = doc.AddPage();
    doc.AddImageHtml( html );
    doc.Save( "testPDF.pdf" );
    Console.WriteLine( $"DPI: {doc.Rendering.DotsPerInch}" );
    Console.WriteLine( $"LOG: {doc.Rendering.Log}" );
    Console.WriteLine( $"OPTIONS: {string.Join(Environment.NewLine, doc.Options)}" );
    float dpiX, dpiY;
    using( Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd( IntPtr.Zero ) )
    {
        dpiX = graphics.DpiX;
        dpiY = graphics.DpiY;
    }
    Console.WriteLine( $"Transform: {doc.Transform.String}" );
    Console.WriteLine($"DPI X:{dpiX}{Environment.NewLine}DPI Y:{dpiY}");
}
Process.Start( "testPDF.pdf" );
Console.ReadKey();
```

**The contents of htmldata.txt is:**

```
<body style='font-family:"Source Sans Pro"'>
    some text on the page
</body>
```

*Note*
**I have done this without the style and it gives the same issue**

---

**What I've already tried:**

1. Spotting differences in events (between Admin vs. Non-Admin) using: [Process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), I could not spot an obvious difference besides paths.
2. Checking if the correct DLL is being used using: [listDLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls), the correct DLL's are being used.
3. Checking the access to the `%temp%` directory as [the docs](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/doc/1-methods/addimagehtml.htm) indicate that `AddImageHtml` uses it to store HTML renders
4. As can be seen in the code I've tried comparing DPI and certain settings but they are all the same.

***Note***
*The reason I'm using `AddImageHtml` instead of `AddTextStyled` is because it supports more HTML (tables and such), so I can't use a different method (if it doesn't support most HTML). The users that use this can't get administrator rights either, this would compromise the system.*

Comment: For people having the same problem: I did not solve it, I switched to a different PDF lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is an old question but I've had a similar stretching issue using AbcPdf11 with Chrome Engine on some Windows 2012 R2 systems (under VMWARE) and I've fixed it by disabling Javascript:

`doc.HtmlOptions.UseScript = false;`

I think that with JS enabled it tries to calculate automatically the `BrowserWidth` based on some system settings.

Comment: Thanks a ton, a I already use another lib now but I tested this and it works flawlessly!